# "Incoming Call" Activity may not be killed on Home Press

Tags: java, android

I am working on a SIP phone app and there are network events like incoming call forwarded from a sticky background service. When this happens, I open up an IncomingCallActivity showing the usual controls, like "answer", "decline", "deflect"(to voicebox) and so on.

While this all works perfectly, even showing a notification when you press the Home Button (so you don't lose the incoming call), it sometimes happens, that Android kills my Activity as soon as I press "Home".

Well, this is bad, there are several network things attached and the notification, when clicked, has nothing to point to when clicked.

In the manifest, the Activity has

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

to avoid, that the notification always creates a new instance of the incoming call.

While I know about savedInstanceState Bundle, I see this activity as kind of "special" -> So, is there a way to force Android to keep my activity alive while ringing, for at least,... say, 30 seconds?

What I tried:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (answer_clicked || decline_clicked || hangUpDuringRing)
        super.onDestroy();
}
```

This was a try to just "not tell Android" that there is a Destroy() pending.
It resultet in:

```
Uncaught application level exception. This is a crash point.                                                                                        
(+) java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity
android.util.SuperNotCalledException
```

Is there another approach I can take for this special case?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is always a possibility.  Anything that shouldn't be destroyed with the `Activity` should belong to the `Service`.

Comment: Can a service play audio - not sure about that? It's things like the ringtone played by the activity that stops if it gets destroyed... I'd even take a solution to disable the HOME button (and the BACK button) while ringing.

Comment: [Yep.](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/musicdroid-audio-player-part-ii)  (Though that tutorial is quite old.  You may want to use `SoundPool` instead of `MediaPlayer`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, that my problem can be solved by simply using the `persistent` attribute on the Activity in the `manifest`.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.RingingActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        **android:persistent="true"**
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>
```

I didn't know about that (I am still new to Android) but no more destroyed Activities since I use this.